# Cordova WP8 SQLite plugin not working

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, windows-phone-8

I am unable to use the Cordova SQLite plugin with my WP8 application. The example is not working. The following is the JS code

```
window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'hello-world.db', location: 'default' }, function (db) {
db.executeSql("select length('tenletters') as stringlength", [], function (res) {
  var stringlength = res.rows.item(0).stringlength;
  alert('got stringlength: ' + stringlength);
  });
});
```

The following error is shown in the console:

> Unable to get property 'openDatabase' of undefined or null reference.
>   Source File: x-wmapp0:www/js/CreateTableScript.js, Line: 2 Unable to
>   get property 'querySelector' of undefined or null reference. Source
>   File: x-wmapp0:www/js/index.js, Line: 41

How to fix this? The WP8 project has been created using Cordova v6.2.0.

Comment: Did you manage to find a fix for this? I am having the same problem

Comment: No, I have not still been able to find a workaround. Please upvote.